# sample size for a single arm study based on median time to event

Tags: survival-analysis, sample-size

In my master thesis, I need to determine and calculate the number of cases for median time to event. The method is according to Brookmeyer & Crowley, 1982. My question is: How can I determine the sample size according to Brookmeyer? So determine the number of cases for median time to event. How can I define the equation for N? I know how to calculate the confidence interval, but my problem, how do I determine the case number theoretically for this.

Edit:

"Designing the trial with different characteristics: planning a single arm study without historical control. How can I determine the sample size N and what method is the best", this is my plan. Assuming "Median Time to event "PFS" ". I want to determine the sample size N and then calculate it, that's why I thought that I can clearly use or find a formula for N. I firmly assume that the survival time is exponentially distributed I want to see with it: 1- Sample size based on distributional assumptions? 2- No implementation available? How to derive p-value? Thanks for further help, best regards

Comment: This is not really a programming question for SO. Once you can define an algorithm then it might become suitable for a programming forum.

Comment: Furthermore the method described in the Brookmeyer paper would not be appropriate for a design where there is a firm assumption of an exponential distribution of failure times.